# PouchDB Sync Error 500 / Couch DB 'Unknown peer'

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

When my local pouchdb is performing an initial (i.e. long) replication from a remote couchdb, I sometimes get an Error Code 500 (*Database encountered an unknown error*) on my client - midway through the replication process.

If I look at the server logs I see :

> [error] [<0.1304.0>] Unknown peer: {error,enotconn} for #Port<0.4817>
>
> [error] [<0.1195.0>] Unknown peer: {error,enotconn} for #Port<0.4812>
>
> [error] [<0.1314.0>] Unknown peer: {error,enotconn} for #Port<0.4826>
>
> [error] [<0.1063.0>] Unknown peer: {error,enotconn} for #Port<0.4813>

Anyone seen anything like tis before ?

Restarting the client by closing the tab entirely (sometimes more than once) results in the replication completing successfully.

Comment: Interestingly. I have moved from **iriscouch** to **cloudant** and this error has gone away AND the speed of replication is much faster

Comment: yeah, this looks like intermittent network errors.